# Build.Gradle ZIP task zips into subfolder

Tags: gradle, groovy

Zipping a package with custom folder hierarchy:

```
root/
  bin/
  dir1/
  dir2/
```

But output is:

```
root/
  bin/
    dir1/
    dir2/
```

Code:

```
task archiveZip(type:Zip) {
    archiveName "CUSTOMZIP"
    
    from fileTree("${projectDir}/path/export/bin") {
        include "**"
        into "bin"
    }
    
    def dirToZip = "${projectDir}/path/config"
    from (fileTree(dirToZip)) {
        include "file1.txt"
        into "dir1"
    }
    
    from (fileTree(dirToZip)) {
        include "file2.txt"
        into "dir2"
    }
}
```

How to preserve this hierarchy:

```
root/
  bin/
  dir1/
  dir2/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove `/bin` from path and remove `into` section

```
from fileTree("${projectDir}/path/export")
```